# How do I get tablists to be created when mobile?

Tags: html, css, tabs

I wrote the HTML and CSS codes below does not have a problem, but I am using Flexbox system and I want my list in this title to be hidden and turn into a tablist on mobile screens, just like the following example; https://hizliresim.com/SSzKQZ how can i get it? (Without Boostrap)
thanks for your help.

```css
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

li{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#wrap{
  background: black;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.container{
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.main{
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.main-1{
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.tel{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.pel{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
    <section id="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main main-1">
      <h1>Hasta Rehberi</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Ziyaretçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Refakatçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Güvenlik Bilgisi ve Politikası</li>
  <li>Şikayet Politikası</li>
  <li>İleri Teknolojiler</li>
  <li>Hasta Hakları Birimi</li>
  <li>Memnuniyet Sağlama Süreci</li>
  <li>Hasta Odaları</li>
  <li>Ameliyathaneler</li>
</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main main-2">
      <h1>Hasta Rehberi</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Ziyaretçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Refakatçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Güvenlik Bilgisi ve Politikası</li>
  <li>Şikayet Politikası</li>
  <li>İleri Teknolojiler</li>
  <li>Hasta Hakları Birimi</li>
  <li>Memnuniyet Sağlama Süreci</li>
  <li>Hasta Odaları</li>
  <li>Ameliyathaneler</li>
  <li>Memnuniyet Sağlama Süreci</li>
</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main main-3">
      <h1>Hasta Rehberi</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Ziyaretçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Refakatçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Güvenlik Bilgisi ve Politikası</li>
  <li>Şikayet Politikası</li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: If I make a decision on jquery, will it be okay for you?

Comment: In fact, it would be better if it was done with html and css, but it may be, but I was wondering how to do it with jquery.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Hey bro  i can't find anyone to help on this matter please come back.

Comment: I thought that you will not use my solution with jiquery. If your problem is solved only with css, then you will need to make changes to the html structure. If jquery worries you, I can do it on vanilla javascript :)

Comment: My only wish is to learn how to solve the problem, if possible, can you show how to make jquery or vanilla with the easiest method. It doesn't matter which one. In addition, I need to change the structure of what in html with css 
but what should I change

Comment: Ok. I'll do it for you on javascript as soon as I have free time. Wait a little, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a javascript solution.

I added the `@media (max-width: 550px)` in your css. When accessing the array, I used the `forEach()` method:

```
Array.from(tab).forEach(function(tabArray, i) {...});
```

The list display type is toggle - the `toggle()` method.

Was it necessary?

```js
function f_width() {  
    let tab = document.querySelectorAll('.main h1');
    let menu = document.querySelectorAll('.main ul');    

    Array.from(tab).forEach(function(tabArray, i) {
      tabArray.addEventListener('click', function() {
      
        if (window.innerWidth <= 550) {
          menu[i].classList.toggle('active_ul');
        } else {} 
        
    });
  });  
}

window.addEventListener("load", f_width);
/*window.addEventListener("resize", f_width);*/
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

li{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#wrap{
  background: black;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.container{
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.main{
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.main-1{
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.tel{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.pel{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.active_ul {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .main {
    height: unset;
  }
  
  .main h1 {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .main-2,
  .main-3 {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
  
  .main-3 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main main-1">
      <h1>Hasta Rehberi</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Ziyaretçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Refakatçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Güvenlik Bilgisi ve Politikası</li>
  <li>Şikayet Politikası</li>
  <li>İleri Teknolojiler</li>
  <li>Hasta Hakları Birimi</li>
  <li>Memnuniyet Sağlama Süreci</li>
  <li>Hasta Odaları</li>
  <li>Ameliyathaneler</li>
</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main main-2">
      <h1>Hasta Rehberi</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Ziyaretçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Refakatçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Güvenlik Bilgisi ve Politikası</li>
  <li>Şikayet Politikası</li>
  <li>İleri Teknolojiler</li>
  <li>Hasta Hakları Birimi</li>
  <li>Memnuniyet Sağlama Süreci</li>
  <li>Hasta Odaları</li>
  <li>Ameliyathaneler</li>
  <li>Memnuniyet Sağlama Süreci</li>
</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main main-3">
      <h1>Hasta Rehberi</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Ziyaretçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Refakatçi Politikası</li>
  <li>Güvenlik Bilgisi ve Politikası</li>
  <li>Şikayet Politikası</li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: No problem, bro :) When you use it on your project, remove this line - `window.addEventListener("resize", f_width)` is an exemplary window resize event listener and is not necessary. If you have any questions, let me know. Good luck.